# How to implement Form based authentication with struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to implement form based authentication in struts2.

My directory structure is :

[image]

My web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Example Security Constraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>manager</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>


    <!-- Default login configuration uses form-based authentication -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description> An administrator </description>
        <role-name>
            manager
        </role-name>
    </security-role>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my login.jsp :

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check" >
  <table border="0" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Username:</th>
      <td align="left"><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Password:</th>
      <td align="left"><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="reset"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

action in struts :

```
<action name= "j_security_check" class="action.LoginAction" >
            <result name="success" >protected/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="error" > error.jsp </result>
            <result name="input" > login.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

my LoginAction.java

```
    public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

        String j_username, j_password;

        public String getJ_password() {
            return j_password;
        }

        public void setJ_password(String j_password) {
            this.j_password = j_password;
        }

        public String getJ_username() {
            return j_username;
        }

        public void setJ_username(String j_username) {
            this.j_username = j_username;
        }

        @Override
        public String execute() throws Exception {
            if (getJ_username().equals(getJ_password())) {
                return SUCCESS;
            } else {
                this.addActionError("Error..!");
                return ERROR;
            }
        }
@Override
    public void validate() {
        if ((getJ_username() == null) || (getJ_username().length() == 0)) {
            this.addActionError("Username Empty");
        }
        if ((getJ_password() == null) || (getJ_password().length() == 0)) {
            this.addActionError("Password Empty");
        }
    }
```

With this i am When i insert same loginid and password, yet i redirected to the error page..

Can someone give a good link for the same..?

The example should contain a protected folder, an action class for login..

thanks..

Comment: i don't think SO is a place to share code? better come up with what you have done so far and what issue you are facing?

Comment: actually m very new to struts and want to learn how to implement form authentication in it.. so i seeking for a start from a perfect example.. on internet there are a few but none is perfect for me. Some lacks with action class and some lacks with a protected folder.. can u help me out plz..

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by protected folder? and what all you need? can u explain it a more?

Comment: the protected folder is any folder which have the protected jsp pages in it simply as resource..

Comment: are u there i have just edited with all my coding.. check out.. I am getting the problem that even after submitting same username and password i am getting redirected to error page.. point out my error plz..

Comment: Hi HashimR I am using Glassfish server..

Comment: if you place your JSP in side web-inf even than they will not be accessible to the end user directly

Comment: Where are your username password stored?

Comment: @umesh : then what url pattern has to follow, let say i have 20 jsp pages that needs to be protected..

Comment: @HashimR I am just checking whether user has given same password and username.. Means if user enters 'jay' as username his password has to be 'jay'.. this is how i am authenticating this form.. u can check out LoginAction.java for clarification..

Comment: It is not how it works. You have to supply a file realm or a jdbc realm from where username and password gets authenticated

Comment: I am very new to form authentication in j2ee.. Can u plz tell me what is this realm and how to supply that..?

Comment: @Rambo Place all of your JSPs under WEB-INF and they're all protected. If you are using an MVC framework like Struts2, then you should not be accessing JSPs directly. Instead, the URL will be to the action which will forward to the appropriate JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to provide username and password combination that corresponds to a user who has already been created in the file realm of the GlassFish Server and has been assigned to the group of manager.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbxs/index.html) is a link on how to create a File realm.

[Here](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/01/jdbc-security-realm-and-form-based.html) is a link on how to create a jdbc security realm.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncby/index.html) is a working example. You can check if it matches with your code.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bncby) is a link to better understand form-based authentication.

Hope this helps. :)

**EDIT**:

The idea behind form based authentication is that you write a JSP or Servlet that presents a form with the following fields and action:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="j_username"/>
    <input type="password" name="j_password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the servlet container checks the credentials for you using the mechanism you've defined (e.g. JAAS). In your web.xml, you set the following:

```
<login-config>
    <form-login-check>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-check>
</login-config>
```

This allows the container to locate the JSP or Servlet containing your form, or your error handling code.

Comment: I think he is just trying to check the form submission and validation.There is no need for creating a db record etc just for checking your workflow. I am sure he will be adding those things later

Comment: In form based authentication, the action that the form is redirecting to is not a struts action. So he can check the workflow by pointing to his own struts action

Comment: On failure from j_security_check, it will always be forwarded to error page mentioned in web.xml

Comment: Yes, but he mentioned that he is entering the username and password, in that case it should not be forwarded to error page. My point was that your post is not the solution for this problem

Comment: @hashimR : Can i do without using realm.. i am not using any database from the action class.. The success is made just with matching of username and password upon entry of form..

Comment: @Rambo Have you tried giving a breakpoint or printing the values in validate() and execute() method. Check if you are getting the right values.Your configuration seems to be correct.

Comment: @anu: You do not need to map the j_security_check to anything. This is managed by the Application Server. 
However you DO NEED to add usernames. roles and realm information. 
Each application server has its own way of authenticating this information.

Comment: @Rambo: You do not need to map the j_security_check to anything. This is managed by the Application Server. 
However you DO NEED to add usernames. roles and realm information. 
Each application server has its own way of authenticating this information.

Comment: Well thats the point. You don't need to map `j_security_check` to anything. I have done form based authentication in struts2. :)

Comment: Maybe this will be more helpful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362581/confusion-in-form-based-authentication-in-java

Comment: +1 oops i got the original question wrong(mixed up with some other concept)